# AWS Amplify Clone feature broken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm working on an Amplify app and can't seem to clone my dev environment - either from the CLI or the Web Console - the Console fails after 15 min without an informative reason and the CLI will run on the command line when I create a new env and push for 23 minutes, but then fails at the very verrrry end...

I would love to be able to use the ability to clone a version of my backend for data purposes, but it's beginning to feel that's not possible - lots of RED when I do anything - any help?